# Error in Bind9 named.conf file. Bind won't start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bind

I'm trying to setup a DNS server on an Ubuntu Server machine (10.04).  I configured an entry in named.conf.local to test it, but when trying to restart bind9 I get the following error:

```
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                                 [fail]
```

So I checked the output of syslog and this is what I get.

```
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: starting BIND 9.7.0-P1 -u bind
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-dlz-postgres=no' '--with-dlz-mysql=no' '--with-dlz-bdb=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-stub=yes' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 'CPPFLAGS='
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: adjusted limit on open files from 1024 to 1048576
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: using up to 4096 sockets
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: /etc/bind/named.conf:10: missing ';' before 'include'
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: loading configuration: failure
May 20 18:11:13 empression-server1 named[4700]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

So it thinks I have an error in the default named.conf file, which is pretty ridiculous.  I went through it and deleted a blank line just for the hell of it, but I can't see how it figures there's an error in there.  Note that before this I *did* have an error in named.conf.local, but it showed up properly in syslog and I fixed it, so it is reporting the correct file.  Here is the contents of named.conf:

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the 
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize 
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that line 10 is the last line of `named.conf`, then this error could be caused by a missing semicolon on the last option in `named.conf.local`.

Comment: This was it.  I was missing a semi-colon after the closing bracket.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That may occur if you missed semicolon in named.conf.local after zone description. Try to add it after closing bracket like this };